# How to view Excel file directly from asp.net 4.0?

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

I just want to view Excel file directly from asp.net 4.0 with C#.

Here is my code :

```
protected void lbut_viewfile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook theWorkbook = 
         ExcelObj.Workbooks.Open(
             openFileDialog1.FileName, 0, true, 5, "", "", true,     
             Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", 
             false, false, 0, true);

    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Sheets sheets = theWorkbook.Worksheets;

    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet worksheet = 
         (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)sheets.get_Item(1);

    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
    {
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range range = 
             worksheet.get_Range("A" + i.ToString(), "J" + i.ToString());
        System.Array myvalues = (System.Array)range.Cells.Value;
        string[] strArray = ConvertToStringArray(myvalues);
    }

}
```

Here I can not get this `ExcelObj.Workbooks.Open`, `openFileDialog1` and  `ConvertToStringArray` I want which specific refrences it diserve.

Comment: This can not work - the code you're showing will run *on the server*, not on the client. How's the server supposed to use an `OpenFileDialog`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't combine ASP.NET and Office together. This is [strongly discouraged by Microsoft](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757). Also you are combining Windows controls, which will run on the server and will never work on the client.

If you want to show the Excel file in the browser, I suggest to either let the user download the file and show it in it's default program, or read the file using [EpPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com) and create the output HTML yourself.

Comment: That's the problem with ASP.NET. Many people don't understand the code is running on the server. There are so many questions here based on that misunderstanding... \*rolleyes\*

Comment: So true. Unfortunately the distinction between web and client is not clear to a lot of programmers.

Comment: Also, they never thought what happens if 10 users at the same time open an Excel file using Office automation... 2GB memory in use.

Comment: ok i got ddl can u provide code to to how to use it and display it.

Comment: There are too much options. Take a look at the epplus website and check out and for example http://www.datatables.net/, which is a jQuery plugin to create nice tables in html / jQuery.

Comment: so i have to manually fill all rows data to that and display it. it's very time consuming could you please provide plugin that can take only file path and display it.

Comment: It doesn't work that way. I don't know any plugins that provide this kind of functionality. Sorry...